# Copy and Paste between Workbooks without using Range

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro that runs through a workbook, copies specific cells, then pastes them into another workbook.  I've seen macros that do this, but they all select ranges to accomplish it.  I'm going to be running through hundreds of rows, so selecting ranges isn't going to work (I might as well do it be hand if I have to code hundreds of ranges).  I'd like to accomplish this by using cell Offsets.

This is the code I have:  I'm only showing the relevant areas.

```
Workbooks.Open (txtFileName) ' Opens the selected file
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Windows("CM activity log referral macro.xlsm").Activate
Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook

' Begin Populating CM Workbook: Caselist Worksheet

'Set initial rows
wbSource.Activate
wbSource.Sheets("Contact Log").Range("A4").Select
wbTarget.Activate
wbTarget.Sheets("Caselist").Range("A3").Select

'Populate Caselist from Selected Workbook
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 200
    'Copy Date Encountered
    wbSource.Sheets("Contact Log").ActiveCell.Copy
    wbTarget.Sheets("Caselist").ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Copy First and Last Name
    wbSource.Sheets("Contact Log").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy                          
    wbTarget.Sheets("Caselist").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteValues  
    wbSource.Sheets("Contact Log").ActiveCell.Offest(0, 1).Copy                          'move to D4
    wbTarget.Sheets("Caselist").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

There's more to copy, and the for loop gets closed properly, but I'm not showing that here.  I know that the problem is that Sheets doesn't support the following .Activecell statement.  I need to know how to write this so I can use offset instead of Range to select the cells to copy and paste to.

Thank you so much for your time.  I appreciate it.

Comment: You can set the value of one range equivalent to the value of another. For example `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SourceData").Range("J5").Value` would take the value in our data sheet from range "J5" and would put it in cell 1,1 on our new sheets (you dont have to use cells. You just have to define the range).

Comment: That might actually work.  I can do like Cells(1+i, 1) to move to the next row.  I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: Not a problem at all. Once you get comfortable with that you may be interested in learning about arrays :).

Comment: You can do `cells(i+1, 1)`, and you can also do `.cells(1, 1).offset(i)`